# nested indentation of lines

Tags: indentation

I am trying to figure out how to configure proper indentation when writing an algorithm in LaTex.

The algorithm code should look like:

```
Let a = 0
let b = 1
if (a > b)
    do action 1
else if (a = b)
    do action 2
else 
    do action 3
all done
```

I could have more than one level of indentation involved in the algorithms, so it needs to be a flexible solution.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should take a look of one of the dedicated packages, most notably ` algorithms`, `algorithm2e` and `algorithmicx`.

Comment: Not sure if I understood, but verbatim environment and lstlisting or minted seems related to me (just for manual indenting)